# DataSet não reconhece LIKE e parâmetros de pesquisa

Tags: c#, mysql, select, operador-like

Boa noite.
Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados MySql e estou utilizando um DataSet para tratar dela no meu projeto Windows Form. O problema é que quando eu tento utilizar uma consulta com o LIKE, esta não reconhece o parâmetro que estou pedindo.
Segue código:

```
SELECT nome FROM aluno WHERE aluno.RA LIKE '%@RA%'
```

Alguém já passou por algo parecido ou sabe como posso resolver esse problema?
Quando utilizo no BD direto, ele funciona perfeitamente...
Edit: Segue ai como print minha tela.

[image: Segue ai print do que estou tentando fazer...]

Comment: Como está o código? Pode editar sua pergunta colocando ele?

Comment: Eu tenho um arquivo DataSet com as tabelas e dentre os Querys desta tabela (aluno) possui esse código.

Comment: Sim, mas não tem um exemplo em código que você possa colocar na sua pergunta?

Comment: mostre a estrutura da tabela também por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o trecho '%@RA%' deve ser substituido pelo parâmetro que você irá informar, deixe-o fora das aspas simples.

Exemplo:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM aluno where RA LIKE @RA";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, stringConn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RA", "%" + variavel + "%");
```